Find inverse of conformal mapping z+1/z
I knew $f(z) = z+1/z$ is a conformal mapping from 2d airfoil theory. I wonder what is the inverse of this conformal mapping. Here is what I tried:
I can write it as $z+1/z=m,$ meaning that $z^2-mz+1=0,$ here I got two roots:
$$z = \frac{m\pm\sqrt{m^2-4}}{2}$$
Does this means that the inverse of a conformal mapping is not unique, and is there any geometric intuition on why there are two mapping and which one should I choose?

$f(z)=z+\dfrac{1}{z}$ is not a conformal mapping when its domain is all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, as it is not injective, which is immediately deduced from $$f(z)=f(1/z),\, z\neq 0$$
When restricted to a domain where it is injective, such as the upper half of the open unit disk, $f$ is conformal and its inverse is one of the two branches you have found.
To distinguish which one is correct, take any point on the domain and plug in its image to both branches. Only one of the two should return back the original point.
